# Internet Explorer Fires Change Events On Keypress

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, drop-down-menu, onchange

IE fires the change event on a select menu when using the arrows to navigate the menu. This is not the case in non-IE browsers. Non-IE browsers only fire the event when clicking on the option, or pressing enter after navigating to the item with the arrows. Is there a way program around this? I need the event to not fire when navigating with the keys.

Answer (score 0):

I would add my own change event listener and handle things that way if I could.  Without knowing all of the details it's hard to say but I'd look there first because the event cannot be cancelled.  Outside of that approach, IE is going to fire the event when the value changes so not much you can do about that.  Here is a link to the [change/onchange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536912%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in IE.  It actually says this in the doc.

To invoke this event, do one of the following:

- **Choose a different option in a select object using mouse or keyboard navigation.**
- Alter text in the text area and then navigate out of the object.

It stinks but one of those you have to account for when using a select field.

Answer (score 0):

The solution that worked for my situation was the following.

- bind to the `blur` event instead of the `change` event.

This introduced another issue, where when I initially load the page the `select` fires a `change` event, and I need the code in my `blur` binding to take effect. Binding to `change` and having it trigger `blur` caused massive recursion. The solution was to create an init function that ran at startup.

```
initData : function(){
    var t = this,
        formSelects = 'select';

    jQuery.each(formSelects, function(){
        // do my code here that normally happens in blur.
    })
}
```